# Firebase Authentication : Phone number authentication in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication, swift4, one-time-password

A localised description is being printed in my output console saying : "unable to get verification: Optional("If app delegate swizzling is disabled, remote notifications received by UIApplicationDelegate need to be forwarded to FIRAuth\'s canHandleNotificaton: method.")"

Even though, I am receiving OTP in my phone as well as recaptcha for verification it is not taking me to next page which where we need to verify the otp received.

My code is till receiving the OTP is working fine, but after that its showing the same page where I need to enter my number.

My viewcontroller.swift has the following code :

```
    @IBAction func mobileNumberSubmitButton(_ sender: Any) {

     guard  let phonenumber = mobileNumberText.text else {return}

     PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phonenumber, uiDelegate: nil) {(verificationid, error) in
                if error == nil{
                    print(verificationid)
                    guard let verify = verificationid else {return}
                    self.userdefault.set("verify", forKey: "verifyID")
                    self.userdefault.synchronize()
                    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OTPVerificationID") as! OTPVerificationViewController
                    viewController.verifyid = verificationid! 
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

                }else{
                    print("unable to get verification:", error?.localizedDescription)
                }
            }



}
```

and my otpverificationviewcontroller.swift has the following code:

```
     class OTPVerificationViewController: UIViewController { 

       var verifyid : String = ""
       let userdefault = UserDefaults()

       @IBOutlet weak var OTPVerifyCode: UITextField!

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           let valust = self.userdefault.dictionary(forKey: "verifyID")
           print(verifyid) 

       }

       @IBAction func verificationSubmitButton(_ sender: Any) {

            guard let verifycode = OTPVerifyCode.text else {return}
            let credentials = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: verifyid, verificationCode: verifycode)
            Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credentials) { (result, error) in
            if error == nil {
                 if let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ServiceViewControllerID") as? ServiceViewController {

                 UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
                 self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
             }
           } else{
               print(error?.localizedDescription)
        } 
    }
}
```

}

I expect the mobileNumberSubmitButton action push the otpverification page inorder to verify the OTPcode.

Can someone give me some solutions?

Comment: check your navigation controller is nil or not.

Answer (score 0):

Do it on the main thread as :

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
    let viewController =
     self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OTPVerificationID") as! OTPVerificationViewController
     viewController.verifyid = verificationid!
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true) 
    }
```

Comment: I tried the above code, but in the output console , it's showing : "nw_connection_receive_internal_block_invoke [C6] Receive reply failed with error "Operation canceled"" - and still I am able to verify through recaptcha and OtpCode is also generated but it ain't  taking me to the otpverificationviewcontroller.swift page.